# Error when running a .exe file using Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, python-multiprocessing

I recently dabbled with `multiprocessing` in one of my python projects.

I would run my script in my terminal and everything would run flawlessly. However, when I turned the `.py` script into a `.exe` using `pyinstaller` it wouldn't work anymore.

I've narrowed it down to the issue being the `Manager()` method.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting")
    manager = Manager()
    print("Worked")
```

Running the script as a `.py` file outputs:

`> Starting`

`> Worked`

After converting to a `.exe` the script outputs `Starting` continuously:

`> Starting`

`> Starting`

`> Starting`

`etc...`

I managed to snatch [this error code](https://pastebin.com/NG13RJmH) after performing a keyboardinterrupt on the running code if any help.

Please let me know if you guys encounter the same issue, or have any idea how to fix this.
Have a great weekend <3

Comment: Possibly related:  https://www.kite.com/python/docs/multiprocessing.freeze_support

Comment: Do you call `freeze_support()`? https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you so much [g.d.d.c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351031/g-d-d-c)
all I had to do was

import an extra method

and add an extra command

The code now looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, freeze_support

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    print("Starting")
    manager = Manager()
    print("Worked")
```

<kite.com/python/docs/multiprocessing.freeze_support>

Answer (score 0):

The thing is...pyinstaller has a lot of problems. In fact, most modules for converting `.py` files to `.exe` do. To be honest, I don't really think it's a problem with multiprocessing, but it might be. I suggest maybe trying other modules to convert `.py` to `.exe`, like `cx_freeze` or `auto_py_to_exe`

Comment: Oh wait nevermind, it has already been solved, sorry

Comment: Thanks for the comment regardless, ill have it mind for future projects, although I'm pretty sure `auto-py-to-exe` is just a GUI build on top of pyinstaller